# binary search on array giving wrong index on java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, binary-search, insertion

I'm writing a code that **does not have to import java Arrays**, and that inserts, deletes, and searches a series of values; but the output prints out that it does not find the values on the list when the `binSearch()` method is called. I have already sorted the array in the main method before calling the `binSearch()` but it still doesn't find the index of the values.

I'm still a beginner in `java`, so it would be nice of you if you can explain it to me at a beginner level.

```
private static int[] insertElement(int index, int array[], int list[], int i) {
    int length = array.length;
    int destination[] = new int[length + 1];
    for (int j = 0; j < destination.length; j++) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, destination, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy(array, index, destination, index + 1, length - index);
    }
    destination[index] = list[i];
    System.out.println(list[i] + " is inserted in the list.");
    return destination;
}

private static int[] deleteElement(int index, int[] array, int list[], int i) {
    boolean[] deleteNumber = new boolean[array.length];
    int size = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j] == list[i]) {
            deleteNumber[j] = true;
            System.out.println(list[i] + " is removed from the list.");
        }
        else {
            deleteNumber[j] = false;
            size++;
        }
    }
    
    int[] newArr = new int[size];
    int in = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (!deleteNumber[j]) {
            newArr[in++] = array[j];
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}

public static int binSearch(int[] array, int search[], int i) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = array.length - 1;
    
    if (left <= right) {
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (search[i] < array[middle]) {
            right = middle - 1;
        }
        else if (search[i] > array[middle]) {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(search[i] + " is found at location ");
            return middle;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    int arr[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 20, 33, 44, 45, 68, 88};
    int index = 1;
    
    //insert element
    int newIndex = index - 1;
    int s[] = {3, 78, 98, 12};
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        arr = insertElement(newIndex, arr, s, i);
    }
    
    //delete element
    int d[] = {20, 44, 89};
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        arr = deleteElement(newIndex, arr, d, i);
    }
    
    //sort the array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                int swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //search for element in array
    BinarySearch ob = new BinarySearch();
    int a[] = {8, 45, 88, 90};
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int result = ob.binSearch(arr, a, i);
        if (result == -1) {
            System.out.println(a[i] + " is not found in the list.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(result + ".");
        }
    }
    //print array
    printArray(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the if clause with while as you have to search at all levels of the binary search tree.
Change

```
if (left <= right)
```

to

```
while (left <= right)
```

And also there is small issue in your insertElement method.

```
for (int j = 0; j < destination.length; j++) {
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, destination, 0, index);
            System.arraycopy(array, index, destination, index + 1, length - index);
        }
```

There is no need of for loop again in the insertElement method as you are already looping through the array that needs to be added in your main method.

Answer (score 0):

i found the error in my code. the binSearch() method should have used a **while** loop, instead of the if loop. the whole code now perfectly runs.

```
    public static int binSearch(int[] array, int search[], int i) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = array.length - 1;
        
        while (left <= right) {
            int middle = (left + right) / 2;
            if (search[i] < array[middle]) {
                right = middle - 1;
            }
            else if (search[i] > array[middle]) {
                left = middle + 1;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(search[i] + " is found at location ");
                return middle;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```